# Deploying App on Google App Engine - Error Response: [13] An internal Error occurred

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a python app on google app engine.

I was able to preview the web successfully on cloud shell editor but when I deploy it, I obtain Error Response:[13] An internal error occurred.

This is my app.yaml content

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b:8078 main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.7

manual_scaling:
  instances: 2
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

It doesn't also show logs that could indicate what is wrong with the application.

Thank you

Comment: 1) Regarding the error from ```gcloud app deploy```, what is the exact command you're using for the deploy? I suspect you're using a wrong flag or option. 2) What url does it tell you is not found? Your ```app.yaml``` file has a port number of 8078, did you include the port number when you opened the url? Also, do you really need that port number? And since you're running python2.7, do you actually need an entry point in your project? Can you run your project locally without any issues?

Comment: The project runs locally without any issues. It even works fine when I preview web in the cloud shell editor. The exact command I used for deployment is $gcloud app deploy.  The url not found is the url assigned after I deployed. As per the port number, not necessarily. I re-run it with changes to the app.yaml file in this documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref  . I am obtaining this error "Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds." Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just to add.. I made changes to the app.yaml file and I am obtaining this error now "Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                                                                                        
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred."

Comment: Post the exact contents of your app.yaml file. Also since you're now getting an error with your deploy, trying running ```gcloud app deploy --verbosity=info``` to see if it will shed more light on what is happening.

Comment: Hi  pls see the contents of the app.yaml file                                                                                                                                      runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8078 main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.7

manual_scaling:
  instances: 2
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10                                                                                                         When I attempted gcloud app deploy --verbosity=info, I got exact same error which I got with gcloud app deploy

Comment: Please paste the contents in your question so it appears correctly formatted. What you have pasted here in comments now appears different from your original post. What you have here shows flex env while your original post shows standard. Which env are you actually using? My original comment about PORT number was because your environment (in your original post) was for standard

Comment: so..sorry. I have edited the original post. Kindly see the the app.yaml file and the error I am getting. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There have been multiple iterations since the original question was asked. OP has switched from `standard` to `flex` and `python27` to `python37`.

I think I've previously come across someone who encountered the error because they had exceeded the 1000 file limit. Since you're using `python37`, I assume you have a virtual environment in your project folder which you first used in running the App on your local machine. You need to have a `skip_files` section in your app.yaml or a `.git_ignore` or [.gcloudignore](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) folder and include your virtual env in it so that gcloud doesn't try to deploy it

You can also check out these other links to see if they can help you resolve your issue

1. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/issues/172
2. https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/M4acI1YElVs

If none of the above, I'm not sure one can figure out the solution without looking at the code. If your code is public, you can provide a link to the github.

Comment: Hi thanks. See the GitHub link below                                                                                    
                                                                                           https://github.com/0ladayo/dash                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                            
Thank you.